# Mongolab and network latency?

Tags: ajax, mongodb, network-programming, mlab

I'm just curious, there's a few services like MongoLab where data is hosted on remote servers.  Anyone who's worked with databases knows that there's a certain amount of network latency, even when all servers are internal.  Is a remote data storage service such as MongoLab a good idea for production environments?

This question is mainly for AJAX based web apps or websites in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found MongoLab to be pretty good. Obviously, you need to think about round-trips in general, and optimising those will minimise your overall latency.

It also makes sense to put yourself into the same data-center as MongoLab (you can choose where). They also have a (beta) service on Azure now.

I've been running services with high-latency (three different geographical regions for browser, web servers and Mongo and it still performs adequately in my case because my interactions are not "chatty".

As you probably know, one of the design constraints with Mongo is a lack of joins, so my data structures have naturally lent themselves to simple Q&A fetching of data. I don't read one collection and then use that information to go look in another (manual joins). As a result, I'm not adding up latency costs with those complex interactions. The worst case is generally a single request/response (or a series of parallel, single request/response queries) so it's the difference of about 200ms total which is acceptable.

But of course, the closer you can get your web servers to your DB the better you'll be.

Presumably, if you're spending enough money, MongoLab et al could roll you a custom configuration, possibly where you can have local secondaries.

Comment: I appreciate the answer.  Just curious, how long have you been using MongoLab for? As for the lack of joins, I've resorted to a "denormalized" approach where each document contains ALL the necessary data to describe that object. Do you see any problems with that? (I know it's really its own separate question but you opened the door with your joins comment =) ).

Comment: About 6 months on AWS and the last month or two on Azure (2.2 beta). Your denormalised approach is fairly text-book for Mongo and I think that will serve you well in reducing overall latency. Having said that, you can still perform multiple parallel queries, even from different questions as long as your queries aren't dependant on the results from each other. That's what I've found at least. For example, a common filter query might be a DACL. you wouldn't want to query a users collection first. Instead, tag all documents with permissions for that user and use the user as a parallel filter key.